# How can I build imagemagick without any asserts

Tags: c++, macos, png, makefile, imagemagick

Right now I'm using the following:

```
export CFLAGS="-O2-isysroot/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -arch i386 -I/sw/include/"
export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk,-L/sw/lib/"

sudo ./configure --prefix=/sw --with-quantum-depth=16 --disable-dependency-tracking --with-x=no --without-perl --enable-static --disable-shared --with-jpeg --with-tiff --disable-assert make
```

The code above still generates an 'identify' tool with asserts. I'm testing this by identifying a corrupted png image. Identify just crashes/exits with an assert. I'm running this on a Mac.

Any suggestions to build release mode without any asserts? 
(I'm anticipating a really simple solution :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running configure do this:

./configure DEFS=-DNDEBUG

The idea is to have NDEBUG defined.

Comment: Hum, I get your point but that doesn't seem to work. I also tried setting CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS with -DNDEBUG but it's still being ignore...

Comment: Cool, it finally worked. make uninstall and make clean didn't wipe the old config files. I rm -rf imagemagick, unziped a clean version and everything works. In the end it's a bit sad the the lib actually crashes with a segfault upon a corrupted png file... I'll leave that for the next fight!

Thanks!